# If $f$ is a homomorphism then it is one-to-one or onto

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism

> Let $f : G \to G'$ be a homomorphism of groups such that $\ker f =\{e\}$. Then $f$ is one-to-one or onto.

My confusion: if $\ker f = 0$ then it is one-to-one, but here if $e = 0$ (identity) it must be one-to-one but $\dim \ker f = 1$ hence it is onto. Please clear my doubt, what is the correct answer?

Comment: The kernel of a homomorphism is trivial if and only if it is injective (one-to-one).

Comment: But here ker is trivial or not what is the dimension kernel 1 or 0 I am confused with that

Comment: What do you mean by dimension in the context of group theory? Are you assuming that $G$ and $G'$ are also vector spaces? In group theory, the trivial subgroup is $\{e\}$ where $e$ is the group identity.

Comment: By the way, the kernel of a homomorphism has nothing to do with whether the homomorphism is surjective (onto). A homomorphism is surjective if and only if its image equals the codomain. In your case the condition would be $f(G) = G'$.

Comment: I'm suspecting the second condition is there either by mistake or in order to distinguish unnecessary stuff. By Bungo's first comment, it is clear that they could as well ask you "Prove that group homomorphism has trivial kernel iff it is injective or Oslo in the capital city of Canada" ...

Answer (score 1):

$f:2\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$ defined by $f(2n)=2n$ is one-to-one but not onto and a group homomorphisim under addition.

In particular take any proper subgroup $G$ of larger group $G'$ then the inclusion map $f:G \to G'$ definted by $f(g)=g$ is a group homomorphism that is one-to-one but not onto.